# Creating Dynamic ID and Use the Last loop as Parent ID

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

Hello im having a problem on how should i properly out this:
[image]

see the **child ID**/`ID` of second loop has a value of `3.1.1`

after that second loop the **child ID** of second loop must be use in 3rd loop as a **parent ID**.

let say in every loop of child add .1 . and the parent is use the child ID of the last loop before him.
**Expected output:**

```
{ID:3.1,Parent:3},
{ID:3.2,Parent:3},
{ID:3.1.1,Parent:3.1},
{ID:3.2.1,Parent:3.2},
{ID:3.1.1.1,Parent:3.1.1},
{ID:3.2.1.1,Parent:3.2.1},
{ID:3.1.1.1.1,Parent:3.1.1.1},
{ID:3.2.1.1.1,Parent:3.2.1.1}
 //and so on depends on loop count
```

**My Trial Code:**

```
<?php 
$count = 6;
$a = "3.";
$b = "3";
$c = 1;
$e = "";
$f = "";
echo "<pre>";
for ($i=1; $i <=$count; $i++){
    if ($c == 1){
     $d =1;
    }
    if ($c == 2){
        $d = 2;
    }
    echo "{";
    echo "ID:".$a.$c.$e.$f.",";



    $parent = $a.$c.$e.$f;


    echo "Parent:".$parent;
    echo "}";
    if($i == $count){
    }
    else{
    echo ",";
    }

    if ($c == 2){

        $c = 0;

       $e =".1";
    }
    $f += $e;
    $c++;
}

    ?>
```

**Logical Error Result:**

```
{ID:3.1,Parent:3.1},
{ID:3.20,Parent:3.20},
{ID:3.1.10.1,Parent:3.1.10.1},
{ID:3.2.10.2,Parent:3.2.10.2},
{ID:3.1.10.3,Parent:3.1.10.3},
{ID:3.2.10.4,Parent:3.2.10.4}
```

More Info ? [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50028788/dynamic-dhtmlx-organization-chart-using-php-and-json)

Comment: By `"ID:".$a.$c.$e.$f.",";` your ID is **$a.$c.$e.$f**. By `$parent = $a.$c.$e.$f;` your parent is **$a.$c.$e.$f** as well;

Comment: but its calculating as number and "sum" them, instead on concatenation.
i double quote them as a string but having a result of sum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function loop(array $parents, $need)
{
    $children = [];
    $isLast = $need === 1;
    $lastKey = count($parents) - 1;
    foreach ($parents as $key => $parent) {
        $id = $parent === 3 ? $key + 1 : 1;
        $children[] = $child = "$parent.$id";
        $comma = $isLast && $key === $lastKey ? '' : ',';
        echo "{ID:$child,Parent:$parent}$comma" . "<br/>";
    }

    $need--;

    if ($need) {
        return loop($children, $need);
    }

    return $children;
}


loop([3, 3], 4);
```

output

```
{ID:3.1,Parent:3},
{ID:3.2,Parent:3},
{ID:3.1.1,Parent:3.1},
{ID:3.2.1,Parent:3.2},
{ID:3.1.1.1,Parent:3.1.1},
{ID:3.2.1.1,Parent:3.2.1},
{ID:3.1.1.1.1,Parent:3.1.1.1},
{ID:3.2.1.1.1,Parent:3.2.1.1}
```

Comment: Hello dude, you forgot the {} "," on the last of curly braces
`{},{},{}`. before i reclick upvote and accept ur answer again item ur answer :)

Comment: @スペースタイム now I fixed that